# как правильно составить поля в БД , Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Не понятно до конца, какие поля должны быть в БД? Свои предположения написал в таблицу ниже.

Это информация – все что есть в тестовом:

> **Задача «Календарь»**
>
> Написать Rest API для ведения личного календаря.
>
> GET /calendar Возвращает все записи в интервале между параметрами date_start и date_end.
>
> POST /calendar Добавление новой записи в календарь.
> Запись добавляется на конкретное время date и с конкретной длительностью в
> минутах duration.
> Также у записи есть поля title (обязательное) и description (не обязательное).
>
> Если запись добавляет аутентифицированный пользователь, то возможно наложение различных
> записей по времени (например, 13:00-14:30 и 14:00-15:00).
>
> Если запись добавляется анонимным пользователем, то наложение времени недоступно.

Насколько я понял, то примерно так:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->date('date');
            $table->date('duration');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите нормально вопрос. Не пишите всё в блоке кода (т.е не через tab/4 пробела). И сформулируйте полностью мысль. А иначе так очень сложно читать и понять, что Вы вообще хотите...

Comment: можете расшифровать задание? понятно ли вам Задача «Календарь ?

мне нужно составить таблицу для БД для этого задания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"date_start и date_end" – это параметры, которые манипулируют промежутком времени по созданным карточкам из полей `date` или `created_at` (`WHERE created_at > {date_start} AND created_at < {date_end}`) в зависимости от контекста задачи (созданы ли карточки или на какое время назначена карточка в инвентаре). Соответственно, это не учитываем.

`date` должен быть типа `timestamp`, потому что учитываем ещё и время начала. `duration` должен быть типа `int`, так как это число минут. Наложения уже в коде обрабатываются, в базе это нет смысла как-то обозначать.

Так как учитывается пользователь, нужно поле с его id, которое ссылается на таблицу `users`.

Получится такая миграция:

```
Schema::create('calendars', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamp('date');
    $table->integer('duration');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: #Vladimir Gonchar А еще можно вопрос

Насколько я понял пользователь отправляет в БД к примеру такие данные : date = 2022-06-07 21:30:00, duration = 30, в данном случае date получается датой и временем начала и закончится должно на 30 минут позже то есть ( в методе перед сохранением в БД нужно к date + duration = 2022-06-07 22:00:00 и куда это записывать? ведь у нас нет такого столбца для даты окончания.

Comment: @user484713 Вы можете его добавить, но в этом нет особо необходимости (только если Вы не боритесь за производительность, хотя это тестовое задание, и вряд ли должно требоваться). Вы можете это всё на лету обрабатывать: `Carbon::parse($element->date)->addMinutes($element->duration)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Comment: спасибо большое